# Simple way to indent unnumbered subsubsection in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I would like to add unnumbered `subsubsection` in my TOC but I still want them to be indented so they are not on the same x-Position as the `subsections`.
This is what I am using in my header:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
```

Is there a simple option I can change to get the desired Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent can be managed with `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{2cm}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked. I am using the \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{scrbook}